# Ideas to avoid sun reflections from plated surfaces while driving

Tags: safety, interior

It is common to find plated decorations in the interiors of cars. They are sometimes small details, but sometimes they take big, smooth, and curved surfaces, to make sure there is some part of it in the right angle to shine and annoy you and compromise your vision at any time while driving:
[image: Megane steering wheel and Scala dashboard]

I have no big expectations of finding possible solutions for this, beyond applying vinyl stickers or similar, but any idea will be welcome. Some of these plated elements have difficult geometries to apply the stickers, so I consider even some kind of paint or more adaptable solution.

Comment: Many older cars had much more chromed items than now.

Comment: I'm hoping for some suggestions also. My car is still under warranty so I don't want to be aggressive. My wife for now puts a hankercheif over face of dash.

Comment: paint the surfaces with a matte finish.

Comment: @SolarMike Solved.

Answer (score 2):

I worked in an open plan office with polished black window cills that put a line of dazzling reflected light right around the edges of the room.

The best solution we found was to lay strips of black cloth which had a pile on the cills (cloth without a pile was also reflective to an extent).

So I suggest you stick bits of that on the reflective surfaces with a mild removeable glue such as Copydex™.

This won't harm the dash/fascia, although the glue will be harder to remove from a textured surface (such as the roof lining). It if proves unsatisfactory, it can easily be removed. Fabric sticks reasonably well, but that brand of glue can be peeled off hard surfaces far more easily than, say, a fabric with self-adhesive backing.